# Auto Start Laptop

Tags: laptop, acer-aspire, acer

I recently found out that one of *my friend's laptop boots on its own when he opens the lid*(**Dell G3**). I tried to make my laptop do the same but didn't find any way to do this. I came up across several terms while searching for a way such as ACPI lid and power and lid option in advanced power settings(This option is not available on my laptop).How do I do it for my laptop? Or is it that only some companies or models of laptop have this feature?(My laptop is **ACER ASPIRE A514-54G**(Acer Aspire 5 11th gen i5 processor model with windows 10 in it.))

Comment: This feature is a premium feature only available on some laptops. I don't think your laptop supports this.

Comment: Before you dismiss the possibility entirely, you should find out, if your friend was simply waking the device from hibernation.

Comment: @Ramhound I myself shut it down and checked it 2-3 times.